# Maven surefire plugin triggers the testsuite more than once

Tags: java, xml, maven, spring-boot, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have two test-suites say A.xml and B.xml.
Here's an example of one of them.

```
<!-- URL Details -->
<parameter name="applicationHostname" value="localhost" />
<parameter name="applicationProtocol" value="http" />
<parameter name="applicationPort" value="8080" />

<parameter name="testDelay" value="0" />

<test verbose="2" name="TestSuiteA" annotations="JDK"
    preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="testDataSource" value="Data.json" />
    <classes>
        <class name="package.SuiteConfiguration" />
        <class
            name="package.functionalTestAppStart.AppStarter" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

Here *AppStarter* is springboot app which gets triggered.

Here's my corresponding snippet of POM.xml

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>IT</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                               <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/suites/FT_TEST_SUITE.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                </execution>
                    <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here *FT_TEST_SUITE.xml* is parent test suite which just triggers the other two test-suites.

```
    <suite-files>
      <suite-file path="TESTSUITE_A.xml" />
      <suite-file path="TESTSUITE_B.xml" />
    </suite-files>
```

When I build my maven project "mvn clean install", the testsuites gets triggered 3 times. How to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use suite files? Why not using the naming convention and let failsafe plugin do its work..

Comment: @khmarbaise For my use case, it is required becoz there are multiple files to be configured and testdata input, which are gonna contribute to test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the **solution** with little bit of change. In *failsafe_version* changing version to **2.13** and changing the **phase** to *integration-test* did the job.
Here's my updated POM.xml snippet.

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>IT</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                 <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles> 
        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/suites/FT_TEST_SUITE.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
                </execution>
                    <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Thanks for all your replies!

Answer (score 0):

Move the configuration section to the dependency configuration and remove executions at all (because newer versions of Spring Boot already define such default settings):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/suites/FT_TEST_SUITE.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I had tried this at first place. The test suite didn't fire at all. Just the build got successful.